# PHP parsing a line from within a Json API page

Tags: php, json, api, parsing

I am trying to convert this script over from finding one set of variables eg(playtime_forever) to finding another variable eg(backpack_value)

```
if (!empty($data->response->games)) {
  foreach ($data->response->games as $game) {   
    if ($game->appid == $game_id) { 
      $playtime = $game->playtime_forever;
      if (($playtime < 5940) && ($playtime > 1)) {
        $fh = fopen("final.".$timestamp.".txt", 'a') or die("Can't open file");
...
```

The page it originally parsed looked like this
http://pastebin.com/rnnCsijd

but will now be this. Pulled from here
http://backpack.tf/api/IGetUsers/v2/?&steamids=76561197992146126&format=json%27;

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1369669066,
        "players": {
            "0": {
                "steamid": "76561197992146126",
                "success": 1,
                "backpack_value": 36412.71,
                "backpack_update": 1369630863,
                "name": ":HIT: Bobo the Monkey Boy",
                "notifications": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A small change but I am unable to make the script do what I want. If you could explain how to go about this and the steps behind it, it would be great. I have been trying for a while but I am unable to finish the script

Comment: The two JSON files are nothing alike. The new JSON does not have any of the keys from the old JSON.
What data and in what way are you even trying to retrive from the new JSON?

Comment: The full code of above is here. http://justpaste.it/2pws. I want this new script to parse out profiles with "backpack_value" of under a certain amount.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly and make it more clear and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the profiles as per your comment, use this code:

```
$profiles = array(); //init array so we can use $profiles[] later
$limitValue = 1000;  //Limit value of backpack_value

foreach($data->response->players as $player) { // Loop thrugh all the players
  if ($player->backpack_value < $limitValue) { // Check the backpack_value
    $profiles[] = $player; // Assign the required players to a new array
  }
}
var_dump($profiles); // Dump the array to browser for debugning
```

Comment: I implemented it and it's not outputting anything. Any suggestions? http://justpaste.it/2pyn (this is the contents of unique.txt http://justpaste.it/2pyo) I am going to mess with it, but maybe you notice something I missed

Comment: I think your problem is here `if (!empty($data->backpack_value)){` since `$data->backpack_value` doesn't exist. You should try `if (!empty($data))` or maybe `if ($data->response->success))`

Comment: that fixed it and it works perfectly. Only issue is I was trying to find something with a minimum value, not a maximum value. I tried this if (($player->backpack_value < 9999999) && ($player->backpack_value > 50)) { and it did not work, do I need to change more?

Comment: you need something like `if (($player->backpack_value > $lowerLimit) && ($player->backpack_value < $higherLimit)) {`

Comment: After looking closer, all the script now does it output the first link, regardless of the results...

Comment: Since this question was technically answered, I am going to pick an answer. MISJHA if you can help me with my next question, please visit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780038/